# Is it possible to send data from a web app to an adobe air application?

Tags: javascript, flash, plugins, air

The requirement in our project is to download a file from a web application without showing the open/save dialog box confirmation in the browser. This seems to be impossible in a web application but can be achieved inside an AIR application.

Is is possible to make the the web application send an URL to the AIR 
application?

Please help.

Comment: It is regarded as a browser safety hazard not to show the dialog so if you manage to do that chances are that your way of doing that is going to be removed. What is the reason for this requirement? Also what is inside the downloaded package?

Comment: @PabloKarlsson, Thanks for the Edit. It is basically a document, to be downloaded from the web application to the desktop file system. The download needs 
to bypass the open/save dialog box.
Also want to know whether this can be done using the web technologies like javascript, jquery, flex ...etc.

Comment: Which browser is this for?

Comment: @PabloKarlsson, Google Chrome ,Firefox and Safari

Comment: Wich open save dialog is it you are refering to? In chrome there is just a bar at the bottom of the screen when you start a dwonload. I doubt you can get rid of that one.

Answer (score 0):

The interaction with a web application is possible in Adobe AIR through http protocols..(by giving `link` attributes in the head of an HTML code. Just make sure that AIR supports the javascripts you are using, because there are some JavaScript techniques unsupported by AIR.